# kubernetes client has been closed (this is expected if the application is shutting down.)

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am running a Spark job on Kubernetes. The job gets struck after few minutes and the stage, tasks in the stage doesn't progress at ll.

I am seeing warning in driver logs "kubernetes client has been closed (this is expected if the application is shutting down.)". I had a look at driver logs, the driver is still running along with all executors. One of the stage doesn't progress at all. Any input will be appreciated.

I tried running job with multiple compute paramenters i.e. by changing no. of executors, driver and executor memory, shuffle partitions etc. Still the job gets stuck at one stage with error "kubernetes client has been closed (this is expected if the application is shutting down.)".